# Collapse git history to tags (combine commits between tags)

Tags: git, git-history, git-history-rewrite

We have a fairly big (1000+ commits) repository with 7 years worth of changes and 6 released versions (each version represented by a git tag). We would like to collapse the history so that prior to last tag, all commits between two tags are collapsed into one commit, bearing the version tag. Thus reducing our repository history to some 15 commits. We would not be doing any reverts across versions.
As a bonus, ideally we would like to keep all people whose commits we collapse as `co-authored-by`. If its important, we do not have any merges which are skipping over the tag into new version from before the tag.

From:

```
CHEAD
C2
C3
...
TAG6
Cx
Cy
...
TAG5
Ca
..
```

into

```
CHEAD
C2
C3
...
TAG6
TAG5
TAG4
TAG3
TAG2
TAG1
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Start with a new branch on the first commit you want to save as is - then squash merge each tag onto that branch and force move the tag. Repeat until you're at the last tag and then replay the last few commits on the new branch. Delete the old branch and optionally rename the new branch to the same name as the old. Then make sure all clones are updates as you will probably have hell to sort out if not.

Answer (score 0):

Collapsing by tag is easy : `git log` has two options [`--simplify-by-decoration`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---simplify-by-decoration) and [`--decorate-refs=<pattern>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorate-refsltpatterngt), which you can use as follows :

```
# --graph is useful to have a clear view of parent <-> child relation,
# you may use --oneline to have a compact view, or drop it if you want the complete
# commit messages
git log --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration \
      --decorate-refs=refs/tags   # <- this indicates 'keep only tags'
```

---

One partial way to get "everything after `TAG6`, only tags before `TAG6`" could be to get the log in two commands :

```
# in a 'mylog' script :
#!/bin/bash

log_history () {
    # get all from TAG6 up to HEAD :
    git log --decorate --graph TAG6..HEAD
    # get only tags up to TAG6 :
    git log --decorate --graph --simplify-by-decoration \
        --decorate-refs=refs/tags TAG6
}

# combine the two commands, and pipe them in your pager
# if you pipe the output of 'git log', git removes the default '--decorate',
# that's why I added it in the commands above
log_history | less
```

The above will give you the complete list of commits you want to see ; the only missing part would be that, in the graph, the link between `TAG6` and its child commit (the commit right above `TAG6`) will not be drawn.

I wouldn't know how to indicate the combination you describe in one single `git log` command.

Comment: Hmm, I think there is a misunderstanding. I am actually looking for ways to collapse history as in "combine all commits between two tags into one commit". The lower list is not a desired screen output its an actual desired repo tree.

Comment: @mmix : do you mean : you want to rewrite the repo's history so that it looks like this ?

Comment: yes, that was the idea. Sort of like we were to use rebase -i of the entire repo and then pick tag commits and fixup all in-between (plus we would like to add everyone in that space into co-authored